# Service не работает когда экран телефона выключен

Tags: java, android

Как сделать `android.app.Service` так, чтобы даже при выключенном экране телефона он работал? Вот его исходный код:

```
public class S extends Service {

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent i1, int i2) {
        new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //..........//
                return;
            }
        }, 60000, 60000);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent i1) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

Запускаю его так:

```
public class Main extends AppCompatActivity {

    Intent i1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle i1) {
        super.onCreate(i1);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_main);
        this.i1 = new Intent(this, S.class);
        startService(this.i1);
        return;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        stopService(this.i1);
        super.onDestroy();
        return;
    }

}
```

В теории сказано: «В отличие от Activity службы в Android работают как фоновые процессы... Служба может продолжать работать до тех пор, пока кто-нибудь не остановит её или пока она не остановит себя сама.». Но как только я отключаю экран телефона, служба перестаёт работать. Она возобновляет свою работу только после того, как я разблокирую телефон. Как исправить эту ошибку?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для того, чтобы `Service` работал вне зависимости от экрана, необходимо его запускать не из под `Activity`, а, к примеру, из `BroadcastReceiver`. По-крайней мере, моя проблема заключалась в этом.

Answer (score 6):

Это не ошибка, это так и должно, дабы телефон уходил в сон и не выжирал аккумулятор. 
Учитывая наличие таймера, может лучше использовать [`AlarmManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html)?

Если же Вам действительно необходимо в таком виде, добавляете разрешение на `android.permission.WAKE_LOCK` и запрещаете засыпать:

```
PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "TAG");
wakeLock.acquire();
// нужный код
wakeLock.release();
```

Comment: А если надо, чтобы телефон заснул и экран был выключенным?

Comment: @Lesperanza и как Вы себе представляете, чтобы процессор "спал", но при этом занимался выполнением кода Вашего сервиса? Насчет ВК в обьяснении - почитайте о Google Cloud Messaging: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/

Comment: Уже решил вопрос. Я не знаю, как это может быть, поэтому и спросил. Пробовал различные варианты решения и нашёл нужное. Можете посмотреть мой ответ. Я же не говорил как я Service должен запускать - из под BroadcastReceiver, Activity и т.д. Мне это не важно.